# .trigger() a .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $forms = $('form.vote');
$forms.submit(function(){
    return false;
});
$('.votebtn').on('click',function(){
    $this.closest('form').trigger('vote_now', [$(this).val()]);
});

$forms.on('vote_now',function(value){
    alert(value);
});
```

`vote_now` should be triggered and popup the value but something's wrong. What is it?

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZHy4/

Comment: Could you recreate this issue in http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `var $this = $(this);`, and the extra arguments will be passed *after* the event object.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XbSp6/)**

```
var $forms = $('form.vote');
$forms.submit(function(){
    return false;
});
$('.votebtn').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);  // declare variable
    $this.closest('form').trigger('vote_now', [$(this).val()]);
});
                                   // second argument, not first.
$forms.on('vote_now',function( e, value ){
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: could you check what's wrong here? I'm adding a class to the button. http://jsfiddle.net/XbSp6/1/

Comment: @user1099531: You mean because the `disabled` class isn't added? It's because you're trying to pass a callback function to `addClass`, which doesn't take a callback. (Well maybe it does if you have jQueryUI loaded.) [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/XbSp6/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is improperly declared. Use `$(this)` instead on line 6

http://jsfiddle.net/PxkpC/

Comment: which brings up the point that if he's wrapping his parameter in an array he may want to access an element (ie: alert(value[0]))